# Replace string inside custom tag with content

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I have a string

`<li>&emsp;Content Test 1</li>`.

I need regEx to replace tags so final result would be

`<ul><li>Content Test 1</li></ul>`

(Remove &emsp and adding `<ul>` but keeping inside content)

I've found solutions for when the content is static, but the user types the content in my instance.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you have a DOM or a DOM Parser available you should not use RegExp

```js
const string = `<li>&emsp;Content Test 1</li>`;
const ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.innerHTML = string;
ul.firstElementChild.textContent = ul.firstElementChild.textContent.trim();
console.log(ul.outerHTML)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add tags in another way to `<li>&emsp;Content Test 1</li>` like
`{ul}<li>Content Test 1</li>{ulc}`

and the use `.replace()` like

```
string.replace(/{ul}/g, "<ul>");
string.replace(/{ulc}/g, "</ul>");
```

the `/ __ /g` is so the `replace()` function replaces all instances of the content within it instead of only the first one